# Observations amongst days

Tags: r, t-test

I have a small set of observations per day. For each day I have X number of observations. I know that day 3 and 9 have the highest number of observations. But how can I do an statistical test for this? I did a t-test with the R program but i only know that there are differnces, I would like to say that number 3 and 9 are highly statistically different. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

"Statistically different" isn't a defined term. Maybe you mean "significantly different". But then you would run into issues such as the fact that it doesn't make sense to say "highly significantly different" (the Neyman-Pearson significance-testing approach produces binary decisions, not scalar degrees of significance), and that a typical test such as a *t*-test would only work as intended if you had decided to compare day 3 to day 9 before seeing the data.

If you lack the time or interest to get into the statistical details, it would probably be best to just show a plot or table of the number of observations on each day.